# Third-Party Video Integration into Web App

Tags: javascript, web-applications, youtube-api, vimeo, flickr

I need to **integrate** a third-party video API solution into my web application that I'm building using JavaScript in the front-end and Java in the back-end.  Using the API, I will need the following:

- **Upload videos** to third-party service
- Right after the video is uploaded, the API should **callback** my app and pass the video **ID** or **URL** (**important!**)
- Display the videos using the provided URL

*I have tried the YouTube API, but it seems that videos are uploaded to a single playlist per app and then the app can query all videos submitted to its playlist.  The API doesn't provide my app with the video URL right after an upload and therefore it is not possible for me to determine which **local user** uploaded which YouTube video.*

**Is there a third-party video service provider that provides for all of the above-stated requirements?**

(*Vimeo, Metacafe, Dailymotion, Break.com, Flickr Video?*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YouTube don't provides an upload callback, but you can use polling to verify if the state of the video uploaded is no longer 'processing'

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_checking_video_status

To identify the local user maybe you can use "developer tags":

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_uploading_videos

*When you upload a video, you can associate that video with one of YouTube's video categories. You can also associate the video with additional keywords, or developer tags, that you use to identify the video. By using developer tags, you can identify all of the videos uploaded through your website or even through specific areas of your website. YouTube will not display developer tags to YouTube users; however, you can retrieve or update videos that match a specific developer tag.*

And then, you can retrieve the video id, and the video url, using search by developer tags